# want to get day name for the corresponding date

Tags: mysql

I have a table setup as shown below.

Table Name: activity.

```
| ACTIVITY_ID |       DATE | ASSIGN_ENGR | TASK_TYPE | TASK_STATUS |
|-------------|------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|           1 | 2013-12-31 |      Sachin |   Monthly |   Scheduled |
|           2 | 2013-12-23 |       Mikel |    Weekly |        Done |
|           3 | 2013-10-18 |        John |   Monthly |        Done |
```

I want to get day name against my date field using query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySql Query**

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');
```

**Output:**

> **Saturday**

Your **Query** would be like this

```
select Activity_ID, Date , DayName(Date) As Day, Assign_Engr, Task_Type,Task_Status From Your_Table_Name;
```

[Dayname() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql provides with [`DAYNAME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a')           # %a: Abbreviated weekday name
```

For more information: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

A simple query could look like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, ‘%a’) AS dateday FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```